# Mongoose update inner field

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have this kind of documents in my mongoDB :

```
{
   id: my_id
   inner_foo : [
      {
         inner_id : id_A
         inner_field : field_A
      },
      {
         inner_id : id_B
         inner_field : field_B
      }
   ]
}
```

When receiving a request, i got two ids, the `id` one (here `my_id`), and the `inner_id` one (here for example `id_A`).
How can I, using JS and mongoose, update an inner field ? such as the `inner_field` field of one of the array contained objet using its `inner_id`

I think I cannot use `findByIdAndUpdate` since I can't make a direct reference to the correct `inner_foo` entry using that method, so how should I do it ?

Many thanks !
Kev.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/2pW4UrcVFYr

Read - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/

```
db.collection.update(
    { id: "my_id", "inner_foo.inner_id": "id_A" }, // find the matching document
    { $set: { "inner_foo.$.inner_field": "id_A_Update" }} // set the value on the matched array index
)
```